# Send Confirmation Emails to Specific Users

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to to send a confirmation email to a specific address automatically based on a field value?  Example:

My form has a drop down box for "Technician Name"  If I select "John Doe" from the drop down, I would like the form to send a confirmation to "johndoe@cognito.com"  However, if Jane Doe is filling out the form and she selects her name from the drop down box, I would like a confirmation email to go to "janedoe@cognito.com"

Is this possible?